# Offlining media files in Phonegap 3.0

Tags: javascript, cordova, media-player, progressive-download

Using the [Phonegap media API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0rc1/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media), it is possible to play back external files hosted on a web server.

Once that file has been played, I wonder if it is possible to save it locally, so that the next time I listen to it, I can get it from a local path rather than from a URL? This is what I mean by "offlining".

However, there is no save() method in the media API. Is the file stored in a cache so that I can pick it up using the [file API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0rc1/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) (provided I knew the path)?

I suppose one solution could be to download the file and then play it, but I don't want to keep the user waiting for the download to finish. I want to start playing the media file a s a p. Is it possible to start playback before the file has downloaded completely, using progressive download, for example?